# Is there any rxjava operator like throttle but not filter?

Tags: functional-programming, rx-java, rx-java2, throttling

Assume that there is a high way entrance and a stop sign.

Here are the rules:

1, The first car who enters the high way instantly without any waiting.
2, Any other time, others car has to wait at least 2.5 seconds after the previous car pass.
3, Please be noted that this does NOT mean all the car has to wait 2.5 seconds.
For example, the first car is passed instantly. 10 hours later, here comes the secondary car. It should pass instantly because the first car has passed 10 hours, which is long ago.
It does NOT make sense to ask the second car to wait 2.5 seconds. But assume there is a third car shows up 1200 milliseconds after the second shows up, which passed instantly. The third car need to wait 1300 milliseconds.

I have the code working with unit test in github [repo](https://github.com/TonyTangAndroid/RxjavaStopSign) and the unit test passed. But I really do NOT like the fact that I have introduced the side effects.

```
    private int passedCarCount;
    private int timeSpanCount;
```

Hence I am writing this sample app in hope of asking rx experts to optimize the code. It will be highly appreciated that if we could get it done in a clean way.

```
package com.tonytangandroid.rxjava_stop_sign.demo;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.Scheduler;

public class ThrottleCarStream {

    private final CarStream carStream;
    private final Scheduler scheduler;
    private int passedCarCount;
    private int timeSpanCount;

    public ThrottleCarStream(CarStream carStream, Scheduler scheduler) {
        this.carStream = carStream;
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }


    public Observable<Car> periodUserActionStream() {
        return zip();
    }


    private Observable<Car> zip() {
        return Observable.zip(rawStream(), internal(), this::value);
    }

    private Observable<Long> internal() {
        return Observable.interval(0, 2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler)
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> initSpanCount())
            .filter(c -> whenCarCountGreaterOrEqualThanTimeSpanCount())
            .doOnNext(aLong -> increaseSpanCount());
    }

    private boolean whenCarCountGreaterOrEqualThanTimeSpanCount() {
        return passedCarCount >= timeSpanCount;
    }

    private void increaseSpanCount() {
        timeSpanCount++;
    }

    private void initSpanCount() {
        timeSpanCount = 0;
    }

    private Car value(Car cmdMessage, Long time) {
        return cmdMessage;
    }

    private Observable<Car> rawStream() {
        return carStream.cmdStream()
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> initElementCount())
            .doOnNext(cmdMessage -> increaseElementCount());
    }

    private void increaseElementCount() {
        passedCarCount++;
    }

    private void initElementCount() {
        passedCarCount = 0;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DelayTransformer<T> implements ObservableTransformer<T, T> {
    private Long last = null;
    final long limit;

    @Override
    public ObservableSource<T> apply(final Observable<T> upstream) {
        return upstream.flatMap(x -> {
            final long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long delay = last == null ?
                0 : Math.max(0, limit - (current - last));
            last = current + delay;
            return Observable.just(x).delay(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        });
    }
}

// Caller
Observable<String> car1 = Observable
    .just("car1")
    .delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
Observable<String> car2 = Observable
    .just("car2")
    .delay(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
Observable<String> car3 = Observable
    .just("car3")
    .delay(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
Observable<String> cars = Observable
    .merge(car1, car2, car3);
cars
    .doOnNext(x -> log.info("Received: {}", x))
    .compose(new DelayTransformer<>(1500))
    .blockingSubscribe(x -> log.info("Emitted: {}", x));
```

I've got this output:

```
[INFO ] 2019-12-28 01:11:06.107 [RxComputationThreadPool-1] App - Received: car1
[INFO ] 2019-12-28 01:11:06.128 [main] App - Emitted: car1
[INFO ] 2019-12-28 01:11:06.189 [RxComputationThreadPool-2] App - Received: car2
[INFO ] 2019-12-28 01:11:07.622 [main] App - Emitted: car2
[INFO ] 2019-12-28 01:11:08.490 [RxComputationThreadPool-3] App - Received: car3
[INFO ] 2019-12-28 01:11:09.122 [main] App - Emitted: car3
```

Comment: Thank you for making the effort in helping me out. The solution works. But I am wondering whether there is a possibility that we could avoid `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: Well, you should be able to use ```System.nanoTime();``` as well.